# sort posts by rate in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I use WP-PostRatings plugin for wordpress website posts rating and it works fine. All I need is to sort posts by rating. For that I added following line

```
   query_posts( array( 'meta_key' => 'ratings_average', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

but it starts to display posts from all the categories instead of displaying the posts only from selected category. Could you please help me.

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) :

//sort by rate             
query_posts( array( 'meta_key' => 'ratings_average', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );

        while (have_posts()) : the_post();  ?><div class="post">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <?php 
        if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings(); }
        ?>              
                        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>                      
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        endwhile; 
                        else :
                            echo '<p>No content found.</p>';
                        endif;
                        ?>
```

Comment: are you getting the current category slug in URL? or any variable ? please add the code with category so we can help you .

Comment: **Never ever** use `query_posts`, it breaks the main query object plus all page functionalities (*as you have seen ;-)*), and it is also slow. Use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query **correctly** to sort by custom field

Comment: Noman, I get the following in url /category/accommodations/hotels/. I do not have code for category. I just have category name in menu and when I click on it, wordpress displays all the posts from selected category.

Comment: Pieter, I just used pre_get_posts and I got Fatal error: Call to undefined function pre_get_posts()

Comment: This is normal category page?

Comment: yes, and it displays posts from selected category but when I try to sort the posts by rate, it displays all the posts from all the categories on the same page.

Comment: It's not a function, it's a filter, look at the codex for pre_get_posts, that's why you are getting a fatal

Answer (score -1):

You show use the Wordpress awesome pre_get_posts action

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', funtion ( $q ) 
    {
            $q->set( 'meta_key', 'ratings_average' );
            $q->set('orderby' => 'meta_value_num');
            $q->set('order' => 'DESC');
    });
```

Comment: This affect all queries on all pages, front end and back end and will cause 404 errors on true pages ;-)